# Using Selenium in C# without opening a browser in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c#, selenium, visual-studio-2013

I have been using Selenium along side C# in Visual Studio 2013.  I will make a call to:

```
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://<insert webpage>");
```

...Which will open whichever WebDriver I choose to use.
From here, I will make calls to links/text boxes/menus as I need to.
However, I was wondering if there is a way to get the information from webpages without having to actually open a browser, and if so, could someone perhaps explain or link me to the right direction?  It would save time and speed up a lot of my programs.  I know applications can get information remotely without actually opening a browser, I just do not know how the process works or if Selenium alone will give that ability.

> I appologize if this is wrong place to ask this question.

Comment: Selenium doesn't support this by itself.

Comment: @FreshWaterTaffy I had assumed not, I was open to suggestion to a new solution, but I suppose I did not make the clear with my initial question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not clear whether or not you need to work with web page (like click on the links, or edit test), but here are two options:

1. You can use [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/).It is headless browser and since there will be no UI execution may be faster. There is a selenium driver for it.
2. You can use [Html Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) to parse the page and [WebClient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) to download the page. No selenium is required in that case. Html Agility Pack will allow you to make XPath queries, find objects by class name or ID. **But: you won't be able to manipulate with DOM structure as you can do with real browser. It is just to parse and navigate over static html page.**

Comment: Thank you!  I will look into both options to see what will be to my best benefit.